# Flask redirection with passing variables not working

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a redirection after user login on flask.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if g.user:
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.form['Editbox1']
    passwd = request.form['Editbox2']
    test = ldap.bind_user(user, passwd)
    if test is None or passwd == '':
        return 'Invalid credentials'
    else:
        session['user_id'] = request.form['Editbox1']
        return redirect(url_for('entry_page'), session['user_id'])
return render_template('index.html')
```

This one can't autoredirect, browser just show message:

> You should be redirected automatically to target URL: /entry. If not click the link.

Clicking manually works fine.
If i don't pass variable 'session' autoredirecting works. How i can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the parameters for the `url_for()` directly after the url function you are referring to, and give the parameter a name that you use in the next function call, like this:

```
return redirect(url_for('entry_page', user_uid=session['user_uid']))
```

So your complete code would look like this:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if g.user:
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.form['Editbox1']
    passwd = request.form['Editbox2']
    test = ldap.bind_user(user, passwd)
    if test is None or passwd == '':
        return 'Invalid credentials'
    else:
        session['user_id'] = request.form['Editbox1']
        return redirect(url_for('entry_page', user_uid=session['user_id']))
return render_template('index.html')
```